# What is the best compress format or techniques to transport data between Kafka and mirror maker?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I would like know transporting data as compress format from Kafka to external Kafka using Mirror maker.I used compression.type=gzip than none. Any other suggestions to improve the data transfer b/w Kafka cluster and disk space.

Answer (score 2):

Compression types have tradeoffs between CPU usage and disk space

Zstd compression is supposedly the best option, with snappy being the best for low cpu usage, I think. Then lz4 and gzip are somewhere in the middle.

In general, you need to do your own benchmarks on your own infrastructure

- https://blog.cloudflare.com/squeezing-the-firehose/

Serialization formats also matter

- https://eng.uber.com/trip-data-squeeze-json-encoding-compression/
- https://medium.com/@nitinpaliwal87/compression-and-serialization-techniques-benchmarking-fd1f34c1098b

Comment: Hi all, Thank you for using the zstd feature in Apache Kafka. I am the person who implemented it, and some additional improvements are working in progress: http://home.apache.org/~dongjin/post/apache-kafka-improved-compression/ Please have a try!

Comment: "Zstd compression is supposedly the best option, with snappy being the best for low cpu usage, I think. Then lz4 and gzip are somewhere in the middle." Definitely agree.